# Plot ACF with lines in R

Tags: r, plot

This may or may not be a simple question. Any help is appreciated.

I have accessed a paper regarding to `GARCH` and `long memory`. It has a figure, particularly Fig. 1.1 that I haven't learnt how to plot it in R. The author said that ACF function has a respective hyperbolic function. It is very important to discover whether the data has long memory or not. So I want to apply this technique to my squared returns. The sample data is supplied in [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hl1dss80nhv2dp/sample.csv?dl=0).

My code is:

```
data=read.csv("sample.csv",header=T)
lret=100*diff(log(data$CLOSE))
acf(lret^2)
```

How do we find the hyperbolic function of ACFs and how do we plot it in ACF graph?

[ACF with hyperbolic line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b0mj.png)

Comment: Paper link: 
http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/HoldingPen/StaricaLongRangeQ.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mikosch and Starica stress that the ACF ***does not*** follow a hyperbolic function; that figure is devoted to showing how a misuse of statistical tools can lead to wrong conclusions - the data is shown in the other windows of figure 1.1 to be uncorrelated! Anyways, that is a discussion for [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

---

You can make non-linear regression fits with `nls`. I have used the ACF of an AR(2)-process with parameters 0.8 and 0.1 as an example (fit will of course be incorrect here but it demonstrates a few of the problems you may experience when working with autocorrelation functions).

```
set.seed(1e2)
## AR(2) simulation
arsim <- arima.sim(list(ar = c(0.8,0.1)),n = 1000)
## Autocorrelation function of absolute values:
myacf <- acf(abs(arsim),ci = 0)

## Fit acf = b*x^(-c) 
nls_fit <- nls(y ~ b*x^(-c),
               data.frame(x = myacf$lag[-1], y = myacf$acf[-1]), #Remove lag 0
               start = list(b=1,c=1))
curve(nls_fit$m$getPars()[1]*x^(-nls_fit$m$getPars()[2]),
      add = TRUE,col="red")
```

Note how I remove the data at lag 0 since `0^(-c)` does not make sense. This is in agreement with what the authors usually do (ignore at lag 0 - never makes sense to plot anyways. Why it is the default of `plot.acf` I do not know).

[image: Code plot output]

Mikosch usually suggests to remove the iid confidence bands that are shown by default when the data is clearly not iid. You do this with the `plot.acf` option `ci = 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Therkel.